# Probe SSH connection and detect ssh disconnect or logout

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh-tunneling, openssh, sshd

I'am running a script to connect to another host (via ssh) and it's doing some deployment work.

I need to detect the ssh connection is closed/or interrupted, then need to execute a command to delete session_directories in the remote host.

I was trying pam_session_close, but it can remove directories with the ssh session_close or disconnect. But I need to do both work (shell script connection to remote host and deploy package then delete the temp directories once session is closed or terminated.

what is the best method to do that?  How can I use a shell script to do this?  The shell script will connect and deploy the work, and also monitor the session. If the shell script detects the session, it should remove temp directories per that particular session. (I can get the temp directory name from my script in that session.)

Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a script that uses `trap` on `SIGHUP`.